# How to include pressing the (ESC) Escape key as a method of closing the popup?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, popup

First of all, based on my codes below, what should I add to the ourOverlay class to trigger closing the modal by clicking anywhere off of the popup? I am looking to expand functionality a bit.

May I know also what codes to add to include the Escape key press as a method of closing the popup? I believe we will be adding addEventListener and classList.toggle

For my content popup box, how can I make its height flexible so that it can adjust depending on how long my content is?

How can I keep .ourPopup .ourContent to be fixed in the middle of my screen regardless of where the div is placed?

I am so sorry if I am asking too much. Your help will be very much appreciated.

These are my codes:

```js
function togglePopUp() {
  document.getElementById("myPopUp-1").classList.toggle("active");

}
```

```css
.ourPopUp .ourOverlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  /* unya nani labi na if ga live server ka */
}

.ourPopUp .ourContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  background: #fff;
  width: 450px;
  height: 220px;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ourPopUp .ourClose-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.ourPopUp.active .ourOverlay {
  display: block;
}

.ourPopUp.active .ourContent {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Simple Popup Box / Modal </title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="ourPopUp" id="myPopUp-1">
    <div class="ourOverlay"></div>
    <div class="ourContent">
      <div class="ourClose-btn" onclick="togglePopUp()">&times;</div>
      <h1>Simple Popup Box / Modal using HTML CSS & JavaScript</h1>
      <p>A simple popup box / modal using HTML CSS and JavaScript.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="togglePopUp()">Show Popup</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these examples!

```
function keyPress (e) {
    if(e.key === "Escape") {
        // write your logic here.
        document.getElementById("myPopUp-1").classList.toggle("invisible");
    }
}
```

Or with addEventListener()...

```
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.key == "Escape") {
    document.getElementById("myPopUp-1").classList.toggle("invisible");
  }
});
```

If you're using JQuery:

```
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
     if (e.key === "Escape") { // escape key maps to keycode `27`
        document.getElementById("myPopUp-1").classList.toggle("invisible");
    }
});
```

You can define css rules to hide the elements with class "invisible". Please let me know if its helped.

Comment: Thank you, Peter. Do you have codes for triggering closing the modal by clicking anywhere off of the popup?  (outside of the popup box)

Comment: You're welcome! I've posted it inside a new answer

Answer (score 0):

Add the following function inside you script tag and load it on window load
as shown below:

```
<body onload="onloadHandler()">
```

```
function onloadHandler() {
            var popup = document.getElementById("myPopUp-1");
            window.addEventListener("keyup", function (evt) {
                var isPopupVisible = popup.classList.contains('active');
                if (isPopupVisible && evt.keyCode == 27) togglePopUp();
            }
            );
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, Sanath.usk. By the way, is this for triggering closing the modal by clicking anywhere off of the popup?

Comment: Not it is for closing the popup on ecapse key press currently.it can be changed for other scenarios as well

Comment: Gotcha! Do you have codes as well for triggering closing the modal by clicking anywhere off of the popup?